# How load activity first then load images one by one

Tags: android

I am trying to download images from remote server dynamically ( no of images dynamically come ). for downloading all images it is taking 30 to 40 seconds mean time user has to wait to see the activity . But it is the worst case that loading activity after loading all images. I want to load activity first then load images one by one.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    readBundle(getArguments());

   v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);


   naslovglavni = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.naslovglavni);

    glavnaSlika = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.glavnaSlika);


    prednaslov  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.prednaslov);
    naslov1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.naslov1);
    podnaslov =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.podnaslov);

        Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())

                .load(rezultat1)

                .asString()

                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result)
                    {
                        ArrayList<String> h2=new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> pocetakVesti=new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> slikeZaVesti=new ArrayList<String>();

                        String htmlString=result;

                        int startPosition1 = 0;
                        int endPosition1 = 0;

                        startPosition1=htmlString.indexOf("<h2 class=\"article-title\"")+"<h2 class=\"article-title\"".length()+1;
                        endPosition1=startPosition1;

                        while(htmlString.substring(startPosition1,endPosition1).indexOf("</h2>")<0){
                            endPosition1++;
                        }
                        endPosition1=endPosition1-"</h2>".length();


                        String naslovG = htmlString.substring(startPosition1,endPosition1);

                        String naslovGG="";
                        for(int k=0;k<naslovG.length();k++){
                            if(k+2<naslovG.length() && naslovG.substring(k,k+1).equals(" ") && naslovG.substring(k+1,k+2).equals(" ")) {
                                //todo
                            }
                            else {
                                naslovGG+=naslovG.substring(k,k+1);
                            }

                        }

                        naslovG=naslovGG;
                        naslovG=naslovG.trim();

                        naslovG=naslovG.replace("<br /> ","");

                        naslovglavni.setText(naslovG);

                        htmlString=htmlString.substring(endPosition1+"</h2>".length());

                        //slika prva

                        String slikaPrva="";

                        int startPosition2=htmlString.indexOf("<div class=\"article-photo\">");
                        int endPosition2=startPosition2;

                        while(htmlString.substring(startPosition2,endPosition2).indexOf("</div>")<0){
                            endPosition2++;
                        }

                        slikaPrva=htmlString.substring(startPosition2,endPosition2);

                        htmlString=htmlString.substring(endPosition2+"</div>".length());

                        startPosition2=slikaPrva.indexOf("<img src=")+"<img src=".length()+1;
                        endPosition2=startPosition2;

                        while(endPosition2<slikaPrva.length() && slikaPrva.substring(startPosition2,endPosition2).indexOf(".jpg")<0 && slikaPrva.substring(startPosition2,endPosition2).indexOf(".jpeg")<0 && slikaPrva.substring(startPosition2,endPosition2).indexOf(".png")<0) {
                            endPosition2++;
                        }


                        if(endPosition2<slikaPrva.length()-1) {
                            slikaPrva = slikaPrva.substring(startPosition2, endPosition2);
                            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(slikaPrva)
                                    .into(glavnaSlika);
                        } else
                            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://www.magazinauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Auto-magazin_logotip-original.jpg")
                                    .into(glavnaSlika);

                        //pre naslov

                        int startPosition3=htmlString.indexOf("<div class=\"calendar-time\">")+"<div class=\"calendar-time\">".length();
                        int endPosition3=startPosition3;

                        while(htmlString.substring(startPosition3,endPosition3).indexOf("</div>")<0){
                            endPosition3++;
                        }
                        String preNaslov= htmlString.substring(startPosition3,endPosition3-"</div>".length());
                        prednaslov.setText(preNaslov);

                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("<br />","");
                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("&quot;","\"");
                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("&#8230;","...");
                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("&#038;","&");
                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("&#8220;","“");
                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("&#8221;","”");
                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("&#8211;","–");
                        preNaslov=preNaslov.replace("&#8217;","'");

                        htmlString=htmlString.substring(endPosition3+"</div>".length());

                        //naslov

                        int startPosition4=htmlString.indexOf("<div class=\"druginaslov\">");
                        int endPosition4=startPosition4;

                        while(htmlString.substring(startPosition4,endPosition4).indexOf("</div>")<0){
                            endPosition4++;
                        }

                        String drugiNaslov=htmlString.substring(startPosition4+"<div class=\"druginaslov\">".length(),endPosition4-"</div>".length());

                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("<br /> ","");

                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("<br />","");
                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("&quot;","\"");
                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("&#8230;","...");
                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("&#038;","&");
                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("&#8220;","“");
                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("&#8221;","”");
                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("&#8211;","–");
                        drugiNaslov=drugiNaslov.replace("&#8217;","'");

                        naslov1.setText(drugiNaslov);

                        htmlString=htmlString.substring(endPosition4+"</div>".length());

                        //podnaslov

                        int startPosition5=htmlString.indexOf("<p class=\"uvod\">");
                        int endPosition5=startPosition5;

                        while(htmlString.substring(startPosition5,endPosition5).indexOf("</p>")<0){
                            endPosition5++;
                        }

                        String podnaslovtext=htmlString.substring(startPosition5+"<p class=\"uvod\">".length(),endPosition5-"</p>".length());


                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("<br />","");
                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("&quot;","\"");
                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("&#8230;","...");
                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("&#038;","&");
                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("&#8220;","“");
                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("&#8221;","”");
                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("&#8211;","–");
                        podnaslovtext=podnaslovtext.replace("&#8217;","'");

                        podnaslov.setText(podnaslovtext);

                        htmlString=htmlString.substring(endPosition5+"</p>".length());

                        String htmlStringSlike=htmlString;
                        String htmlStringTekst=htmlString;
                        String htmlStringTekstKodSlika=htmlString;

                        int startPosSlikaKodTeksta=htmlStringTekstKodSlika.indexOf("<div class=\"shortcode-content\">");
                        int endPosSlikaKodTeksta=startPosSlikaKodTeksta+"<div class=\"shortcode-content\">".length();

                        while(htmlStringTekstKodSlika.substring(startPosSlikaKodTeksta,endPosSlikaKodTeksta).indexOf("<!-- END .shortcode-content -->")<0){
                            endPosSlikaKodTeksta++;
                        }
                        htmlStringTekstKodSlika=htmlStringTekstKodSlika.substring(startPosSlikaKodTeksta,endPosSlikaKodTeksta);

                        while(htmlStringTekstKodSlika.length()>0){

                            startPosSlikaKodTeksta=htmlStringTekstKodSlika.indexOf("<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">");
                            if(startPosSlikaKodTeksta>0){
                                String pasusUTekstuKodSlike=null;

                                startPosSlikaKodTeksta+="<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">".length();
                                endPosSlikaKodTeksta=startPosSlikaKodTeksta;

                                while(htmlStringTekstKodSlika.substring(startPosSlikaKodTeksta,endPosSlikaKodTeksta).indexOf("</p>")<0){
                                    endPosSlikaKodTeksta++;
                                }

                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike = htmlStringTekstKodSlika.substring(startPosSlikaKodTeksta, endPosSlikaKodTeksta);   //e sad ja...

                                htmlStringTekstKodSlika=htmlStringTekstKodSlika.substring(endPosSlikaKodTeksta);


                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace("<strong>","");
                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace("</strong>","");

                                int poc=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.indexOf("<a href=");
                                while(poc>0) {
                                    int kraj = poc;
                                    while (pasusUTekstuKodSlike.substring(poc, kraj).indexOf(">") < 0) {
                                        kraj++;
                                    }
                                    String link = pasusUTekstuKodSlike.substring(poc, kraj);
                                    pasusUTekstuKodSlike = pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace(link, "");

                                    poc = pasusUTekstuKodSlike.indexOf("<a href=");
                                }

                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace("&#8220;","\"");
                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace("&#8221;","\"");
                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace("</p>","");
                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace("</a>","");
                                pasusUTekstuKodSlike=pasusUTekstuKodSlike.replace("<br />","");

                                listaTekstaKodSlika.add(pasusUTekstuKodSlike);

                            }
                            else break;

                        }

                        int startPositionTekst=htmlStringTekst.indexOf("<div class=\"shortcode-content\">");
                        int endPositionTekst=startPositionTekst+"<div class=\"shortcode-content\">".length();

                        while(htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst,endPositionTekst).indexOf("<!-- END .shortcode-content -->")<0){
                            endPositionTekst++;
                        }

                        htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst,endPositionTekst);

                        while(htmlStringTekst.length()>0){


                            startPositionTekst=htmlStringTekst.indexOf("<p>");
                            if(startPositionTekst>0){
                                String pasusUTekstu=null;

                                startPositionTekst+="<p>".length();
                                endPositionTekst=startPositionTekst;

                                while(htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst,endPositionTekst).indexOf("</p>")<0){
                                    endPositionTekst++;
                                }

                                pasusUTekstu = htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst, endPositionTekst);   //e sad ja...

                                htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.substring(endPositionTekst);


                                pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("<strong>","");
                                pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("</strong>","");

                                int poc=pasusUTekstu.indexOf("<a href=");
                                while(poc>0) {
                                    int kraj = poc;
                                    while (pasusUTekstu.substring(poc, kraj).indexOf(">") < 0) {
                                        kraj++;
                                    }
                                    String link = pasusUTekstu.substring(poc, kraj);
                                    pasusUTekstu = pasusUTekstu.replace(link, "");

                                    poc = pasusUTekstu.indexOf("<a href=");
                                }

                                pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("&#8220;","\"");
                                pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("&#8221;","\"");
                                pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("</p>","");
                                pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("</a>","");
                                pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("<br />","");

                                if(pasusUTekstu.indexOf("img")<0) listaTeksta.add(pasusUTekstu);

                            }
                            else break;

                        }

                        int startPositionSlika=htmlStringSlike.indexOf("<div class=\"shortcode-content\">");
                        int endPositionSlika=startPositionSlika+"<div class=\"shortcode-content\">".length();

                        while (htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf("<!-- END .shortcode-content -->") < 0) {
                            endPositionSlika++;
                        }
                        htmlStringSlike=htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika,endPositionSlika);

                        while(htmlStringSlike.length()>0){

                            startPositionSlika = htmlStringSlike.indexOf("src=");
                            if(startPositionSlika>0) {

                                String slikaUTekstu=null;
                                startPositionSlika+= "src=".length() + 1;

                                endPositionSlika = startPositionSlika;

                                while (htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".jpg") < 0 &&  htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".jpeg") < 0 && htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".png") < 0) {
                                    endPositionSlika++;
                                }

                                slikaUTekstu = htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika);

                                htmlStringSlike=htmlStringSlike.substring(endPositionSlika);

                                listaSlika.add(slikaUTekstu);

                            }
                            else break;

                        }

                        for(int i=0;i<listaSlika.size() ;i++) {

                            if(i<listaTeksta.size()) {
                                textTv[i] = (TextView) v.findViewById(nizTekstaID[i]);
                                textTv[i].setText(listaTeksta.get(i));
                            }

                            slikaTv[i] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(nizSlikaID[i]);

                           Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(listaSlika.get(i)); // programski slika u dodati layout


                            v.findViewById(mLayoutIdArray[i]).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }



                    }

    });

    LinearLayout layouttekstglavnevesti1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layouttekstglavnevesti1);

    layouttekstglavnevesti1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   // layouttekstglavnevesti1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
   // layouttekstglavnevesti1.getBackground().setAlpha(120);

    return v;

}
```

Comment: If I understood the question, images don't load. Try `Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(listaSlika.get(i)).into(slikaTv[i])`

Comment: No no, they are loading. but when activity creates it freezes till all pictures load. What i want to activity start, than load image one by one

Comment: Where are you call loading cycle in activity's lifecycle?

Comment: in Fragments oncreateView method

Comment: Hmm, what is size of listaSlika?

Comment: I parsed html from web, and parsed image url i added to listaslika. It depends, but size  of listaslika can in some cases can be to 15-20 images.

Comment: Check this size, because Picasso load images asynchronously and doesn't block UI. Do you have some another code in `onCreate/onCreateView/onViewCreated/onStart/onResume`? Show all code in the post.

Comment: Check, my update, whole parsing is in oncreateView method. Idk how to do this outside  oncreateView method becouse when i try to call method for parsing  Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) outside oncreateView from class other class i get nullpointerExepction for getApplicationContext()).

Comment: Too much code in `onCreateView` ;) Try to add Log line before your image loading cycle and check it in logcat. I think UI block's in code above this cycle and images loads very fast (I think you test in wifi connection). You need to parse html asynchronously. Now you parse in UI thread. And don't use translit for names in the future ;)

Comment: Ok i will try to do parsing in AsyncTask Thx a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse HTML asynchronously. Now you are parsing in callback which called in UI thread.

Images loads very fast, because I think you test app in wifi network.

Comment: Do you know maybe any way to parse HTML in thread that is not asyncTask?

Comment: Use SingleThreadPool for example, or use rxjava. Or just use java threads